# Get body of Expression<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, wpf, func

In my application I have several parts where I use an `Expression<Func<T>>`. I use this to invoke `OnPropertyChanged` with it. For example if I have an `ObservableCollection<LogEntr>` I use it like:

```
public ObservableCollection<LogEntry> Level1Elements
{
    get { return Get(() => Level1Elements); }
    set { Set(() => Level1Elements, value); }
}
```

Now I want to pass this `Expression<Func<ObservableCollection<LogEntry>>>>` to a method and access the `ObservableCollection<LogEntry>`. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to pass the "real" collection?

I have a custom implemantation of the `ObservableCollection` (ExtendedObservableCollection). There I can call AddItems and pass an `IList`. After the call of AddItems I have to call `OnPropertyChanged(() => Level1Elements);`

So every time I want to add items to an `ExtendedObservableCollection` I have to call:

```
Collection.AddItems(newItems);
OnPropertyChanged(() => Collection);
```

Now I want to encapsulate this into a method. At the moment the method looks like:

```
private void AddItemsToCollectionAndInvokePropertyChanged<T,U>(ExtendedObservableCollection<T> collection, IList<T> addItems, Expression<Func<U>> propertyNameExpression)
{
 collection.AddItems(addItems);
 OnPropertyChanged(propertyNameExpression);
}
```

This call now looks like:

```
AddItemsToCollectionAndInvokePropertyChanged(Level1Elements, output.Levels, () => Level1Elements);
```

But I hope that there is a way to extract the Level1Elements-ExtendedObservableCollection from the Expression.

---

**Final solution:**

```
private void AITCAIPC<T, U>(Expression<Func<U>> expression, IList<T> addItems)
    where U : ExtendedObservableCollection<T>
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member;
    U u = (U)propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
    u.AddItems(addItems);
    OnPropertyChanged(expression);
}
```

And the call now looks like:

```
AITCAIPC(() => Level1Elements, output.Levels);
```

Comment: can you provide code sample what you want do?

Comment: so, you want call like `AddItemsToCollectionAndInvokePropertyChanged(Level1Elements, output.Levels)`?

Comment: Yes. Or with `AddItemsToCollectionAndInvokePropertyChanged(()  => Level1Elements, output.Levels);`

Comment: doesn't this fire the `OnPropertyChanged` with `() => ...` in the property name?  Or does your `OnPropertyChanged` method handle that?

Comment: The `OnPropertyChanged`-Method fires the OnPropertyChanged-Event. Therefor I resolve the Expression with:`internal void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
 MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
 string propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
 OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this will always be used on properties on the current object, the below should work - and builds on top of what you've got in your comment:

```
private void AddItemsToCollectionAndInvokePropertyChanged<T,U>(Expression<Func<U>> propertyNameExpression, IList<T> addItems)
{
    var p = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)propertyNameExpression.Body).Member;
    var c = (ExtendedObservableCollection<T>)p.GetValue(this, null);
    c.AddItems(addItems);
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyNameExpression);
}
```

Comment: This wont compile. Because `c.AddItem(addItems);` could not be resolved.

Comment: @Tomtom just add constraint  like `where T : ExtendedObservableCollection`

Comment: @Tomtom or also you can use reflection for calling this method

Comment: @Tomtom I had the wrong cast - it should be casting to `ExtendedObservableCollection<T>`.  Updated the answer.